# Define a relation on R

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

Given the following proof:

Let A = {2,3,4,5} and B = {9,16,20}. Define a relation R from A to B by aRb if and only if (i) a|b and (b\a) - 1 is a prime number.

How would I create said relation on R and determine if it is a function or not?

Comment: u could make a function with many branches, in way u can satisfy a well defined function.

Answer (score 1):

You first check each element of $A$ and find out which elements of $B$ it is related to. In order for this to define a function, it must be well defined. That means that every element in $A$ must be related to something in $B$, and can't be related to more than one thing.

Then you have something mapping every element in $A$ to something in $B$, and you have a well defined function. If any of the above conditions break, you don't.

Comment: How do I define a relation @Matt

Comment: You've been told how to define your relation. An element $a$ in $A$ is related to an element $b$ in $B$ if and only if the conditions you've been given hold. Otherwise the two things are not related.

Comment: Since there are 4 elements in A and 3 elements in B, there is no way that R can be a function since either one element in A won't map to an element in B or an element in A maps to more than one element in B, correct?

Comment: Incorrect. What you just said doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Coinbase1031 "one element in A won't map to an element in B" - This is just false. Consider, for example, $f : \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \rightarrow \{1, 2, 3\}$ given by $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = f(4) = 1$. "an element in A maps to more than one element in B" This also isn't true, again, by the above.

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting correctly,

$a$ are the elements of $ A$ and $b$ are elements of $B$

---

For (i) $ a|b $
Which implies " $a$ divides $b$ exactly ",

The required relation in roster form in this case is,

$ R = { (2,16) , (2,20) , (4,16) , (4,20) , (5,20) } $

For (ii) $ \frac{b}{a} - 1 $ is prime,

$ R_1 = {(3,9) , (2,16), (4,16) , (5,20)} $

Since, in  $R$ , the element "$2$" of set $A$ has two images  in set $B$ , so this relation isn't a function.

While in $R_1$ each element of $A$ has unique image in $B$,  So this relation is a function.

Now if we combine both $R$ and $R_1$ we get,
$ R_{final} = {(2,16),(4,16),(5,20)} $

In this, each element  doesn't have an image on $B$.
So it is NOT a function.

Comment: We need to find the relation that matches both (i) and (ii). So that would mean R is (2,16), (4,16) and (5,20) which is not a function since not every element in A matches to an element in B